# Eclipse insertion of multiple comment lines

Tags: eclipse

At present if I type "/*" and press enter 
I get the follwing .

```
/*
*
*/
```

Is there a setting somewere that allwos me to make the default like this

```
/*
* TESTING 
*/
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there is! Assuming you want to change the Java code templates (though it's similar for other plugins too):

First, go to Window -> Preferences.
[image: Window Dialog]

Then, Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments.
[image]

---

Now that I have a better idea of what you are looking for, I think what you want is to define a custom code template.

Again, go to Window -> Preferences.

Then, Java -> Editor -> Templates. Create a new template.

Under name give it something like 'xxx' so you won't collide with other reserved words (unfortunately, anything with / or /* is reserved). For the pattern, just add the following:

```
/*
 * TESTING
 */
```

[image: Custom Template]

Now, when you type 'xxx' then CTRL+<space> in the editor, it will replace it with your comment template.

See also: [Eclipse Code Templates (pdf)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-code-templates/os-eclipse-code-templates-pdf.pdf)

Comment: Or, you want non-Javadoc comment templates?

Comment: Not a problem, instead of going to Java -> Editor -> Templates you'll go to C/C++ -> Editor -> Templates.